# add slide animation for angular directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have dynamic loading htmls, I created a directive inorder to load the html template.

main.html:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click='toggle()'></button>
<div class="anim">
        <app show='modalShown'></app>
    </div>
```

sub.html:

```
<div id="sub"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.toggle = function() {
            $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
            var htmlcontent = $('.addtl');
            htmlcontent.load('sub.html');
            $compile(htmlcontent.contents())($scope);
        };
```

app.js:

```
app.directive('app', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                show: '='
            },
            replace: true, // Replace with the template below
            transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.dialogStyle = {};
                if (attrs.width)
                    scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
                if (attrs.height)
                    scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
                scope.hideModal = function() {
                    scope.show = false;
                };
            },
            template:
                "<div class='ng-modal check-element animate-show' ng-show='show' >" +
                    "<div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>" +
                        "<div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>Close</div>" +
                            "<div class='addtl'></div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                        "<div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>"
        };
    });
```

Onclick of the button the corresponding html template will open and close. I am trying to add the effect of slide up and down inorder to make my template look beautiful.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are hiding and showing the modal using ng-show, you can use the built in CSS animation classes to provide your transitions (e.g. .ng-hide-add, .ng-hide-remove).

Have a look at this like for more detail: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-ngshow-and-ng-hide

Also, don't forget to include the ngAnmiate module in your app.

```
.animate-show-animation.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show-animation.ng-hide-remove {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;

  /* remember to add this */
  display:block!important;
  opacity:1;
}
.animate-show-animation.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: I've added an example which shows how to fade the modal in.  To slide up it all depends on where your modal is to begin with.  Basically, you need to animate 'top' instead of 'opacity' from your desired start position to the end position.

Answer (score 0):

use the ng-animate module, which ng-show and ng-hide support really nicely. Here is an example of the CSS classes i use to transition between pages in a mobile app i have. This causes the pages to slide in/out to the left/right. slideInFromLeft slides in from the left when shown, and slides out the to left when hiding. slideInFromRight does the same thing, but from the Right rather than the left. To make this work with sliding in from the top/bottom, you'll need to change the positioning to Top/Bottom accordingly.

```
.slideInFromLeft, .slideInFromRight {
    width: 100%;
}

.slideInFromLeft.ng-hide-add, .slideInFromLeft.ng-hide-remove, .slideInFromRight.ng-hide-add, .slideInFromRight.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.3s;
    transition: all linear 0.3s;
    display: block !important;
}

.slideInFromLeft.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.slideInFromLeft.ng-hide-remove {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
}

.slideInFromRight.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.slideInFromRight.ng-hide-remove {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}

.slideInFromLeft.ng-hide-add,
.slideInFromLeft.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    left: 0;
}

.slideInFromRight.ng-hide-add,
.slideInFromRight.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: As per my code what I need to include more. Can you please work on my code. The css is not working.

Comment: I am not going to write your code for you. What I have done is provide a snippet of CSS from a working example, that you can use as a reference to solve your problems. My advice is to start simple. Start with trying to animate the showing/hiding of a static element on a basic page. When you get that right, then work on your modal directive. There's some very basic examples, with their code on this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations